# Cheap pass by value vs pass by constant reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

Specifically with regard to MSVC on VS 2019, what does `const &` on cheap objects look like with maximum optimization? Can one say for certain that it is always at least not detrimental to do things by `const &`?

```
void foo( char );
void foo( const char & );
```

I know it's implementation defined as to whether or not a reference is a pointer but I just want to know specifically for MSVC's implementation if it is actually bad to have `const &` everywhere.

If so, should I specialize heavily used template functions to pass by value instead of reference for primitives with size < ptr?

Comment: I'm not sure that `sizeof(void*)` is a good basis for determining if a value should always be passed-by-value - considering how modern compilers and processors can do some weird tricks with SIMD to pass large arguments in registers (not to mention function-inlining!).

Comment: I figured that, especially in 2020, compilers should ALWAYS figure out if it's better to pass by const-ref or not, but I can never be too sure with MSVC.

Comment: Anyway - I'm more concerned that you're doing this as a _premature_ microoptimization ([which is a bad thing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil), and [never try to outsmart the compiler](https://wiki.c2.com/?OutsmartingTheCompiler)!)

Comment: I just found this from 2 years ago - someone trying to do the exact same thing as you: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/372105/is-passing-arguments-as-const-references-premature-optimization - and the answers seem to suggest (to my surprise, I'll admit) that we _should_ always prefer `const &` over by-value, huh!

Comment: >>> I have been taught / learned that non-trivial function arguments (i.e. most non-primitive types) should preferably be passed by const reference - quite a few books I've read recommend this as a "best practice". <<<

  I've actually seen the opposite, thus resulting in this question... Books never do agree, do they? Anyway, if this is the case, then why does the standard usually not do this? Things like initializer lists are always passed by copy-of-value.

Comment: That depends on _what specifically and exactly_ those books said - and context is important. E.g. it would be good-advice to advise against by-ref parameters in a book about writing for a resource-constraint embedded device with a compiler last updated in 1995 with multiple threads mutating thread local state, etc.

Comment: I agree with John Zwinck's answer - in general, no.  The answer is only "yes" if you have evidence of a need through profiling, otherwise it is premature optimisation.     More broadly, there is no simple rule of "pass by reference for these types, and by value for others", since the cost of passing arguments depends on too many properties of the host system and the compiler.   Unless you know your hardware and host system intimately, and have done profiling, any answer to this question is opinion-based.

Comment: @Peter any reason for `_Ty const` to exist?

Comment: @nowi Only in code used by an implementation, for example in a standard header or in code used to implement part of the C++ standard library.  An identifier like `_Ty` is reserved by the standard for use by the implementation - and the implementation can do whatever the implementers deem fit.   Any usage by code that is not part of the implementation has undefined behaviour.  If you're looking at standard headers (bundled with your compiler) for clues to answer this question, then any answers will be specific to your implementation - not for C++ in general (e.g. if built with other compilers).

Answer (score 2):

> If so, should I specialize heavily used template functions to pass by value instead of reference for primitives with size < ptr?

In general, no.  Template functions almost always have their entire definition visible where called, which means if your optimizing compiler (of which MSVC is a very good one) sees an opportunity, it will not be thwarted by which way you chose.

Of course there are exceptions to every rule, including templates whose definitions are not visible (and e.g. use explicit instantiation), and when calling a function via function pointer rather than by name.

99.5% of the time, you should not worry about this at all.  If you want to spend time on performance, spend it on profiling.

Comment: Any reason for `_Ty const` to exist?

Comment: @nowi: I don't know what `_Ty const` means.  I mean I can guess it is a template type which is const qualified but I'm not sure what you're asking beyond that.

Comment: Just any type that is const. If `_Ty const &` is better then why does `_Ty const` exist as a parameter

Comment: @nowi: For compatibility with C.  For times when you actually want a copy so you can modify the argument without affecting the caller.  For those few cases where you actually do discover that it's better to pass something by value for performance or safety or other reasons.